# Custom Styled Input field in react js

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux, customization, input-field

I am looking for input field which take the input in formated way based on user selection of font, bullets and code type.

Provided the image below

[image]

Code should be in React Js and output can be html in json format

Comment: You can use third party libraries like: https://www.npmjs.com/package//react-draft-wysiwyg , https://draftjs.org/ ...

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to say you need to implement a rich text editor using React?
Well, in that case I personally use `jodit-react` because it's open-source, works well with TypeScript and NextJS and outputs the text in `HTML` format. You can find the project [here](https://github.com/jodit/jodit-react) and basic implementation looks like this.

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useMemo} from 'react';
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

const Example = ({placeholder}) => {
    const editor = useRef(null)
    const [content, setContent] = useState('')

    const config = useMemo({
        readonly: false // all options from https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/,
        placeholder: placeholder || 'Start typing...'
      }, 
    [placeholder])

    return (
        <JoditEditor
            ref={editor}
            value={content}
            config={config}
            tabIndex={1} // tabIndex of textarea
            onBlur={newContent => setContent(newContent)} // preferred to use only this option to update the content for performance reasons
            onChange={newContent => {}}
        />
    );
}
```

Take a look at this example below.
[image]

Hope this helps!
Cheers!

Comment: What is the format of output ? Will it be able to save as html ?

Comment: @Ankitsaxena It saves as HTML by default. You can put it into a state on change and try logging it. You can also get the text out of it using this simple regex `const finalContent = content.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")`